# Discord.py Add Role Command

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I Just Started Making a Discord Bot. I Wanna Make a Command Where You Can Type -queue duos to Queue a Game With Others Who Also Want to. However, My Add Role Command Is Completely Unresponsive and Doesn't Give a Role or Error When I Type The Command Into Discord.

```
import discord
import os


#run the Bot and a message to make sure it ran
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
#Detects if someone queues
    if message.content.startswith('-queue duos'):

        await message.channel.send('you have joined the duos queue.')

        async def role(ctx, member : discord.Member, role : discord.Role):
          await member.add_roles(role)
     

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "*My code does not work*" is not really helpful. What exactly is not working? What have you tried so far? You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined but didn't called the role function.
I suppose you saw a tutorial using discord.ext.commands and tried to create a command.
I recommend you to use discord.ext.commands.Bot instead of discord.Client.
It is a subclass of Client so you can do the same.
Example:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')
botId = 

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("with your servers"))
    print("Bot is ready")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == f"<@{botId}>" or message.content == f"<@!{botId}>":
        await message.channel.send("My prefix is -")
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def role(ctx, member:discord.Member, role:discord.Role, *reason):
    Reason = ' '.join(reason)
    try:
        await member.add_roles(role, reason=Reason)
        await ctx.channel.send("Role added to member")
    except:
        await ctx.channel.send("I suppose I don't have the permission to do that")

bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you were trying to do this in an event. For that you need to identify the `author` of the `message` and then assign a role to it. You make a few mistakes in your code, because another function **does not** belong in an event.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    # detects if someone queues
    if message.content.startswith('-queue duos'):
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=RoleID) # Define the role
        await message.author.add_roles(role) # Add the role to the author
        await message.channel.send('you have joined the duos queue.')
```

**What did we do?**

- Define the role through `discord.utils.get`
- Identified the author of the message and assigned the role

*Maybe also take a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) again*

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I really appreciate it! It was very clear and detailed and I learned what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that this isn't registered as command. You should do it with special conditions for the role command and register it outside with [`@client.command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#decorators) (for what you would have to "migrate" to [`commands.Bot()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#bot)) or if you want to stay in on_message then with [`client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

Example:

```
import discord
import os


#run the Bot and a message to make sure it ran
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
#Detects if someone queues
    if message.content.startswith('-queue duos'):

        await message.channel.send('You have joined the duos queue.')

        await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == message.author and m.content == '-role')

        role = # Define the role you want to add if you haven't before
        await member.add_roles(role)
 

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```